# AWS CLI - aws ec2 describe-instances to retrieve keypair mame for each EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to query keypair names that are attached to each EC2 instance, the ec2 describe-instances below works fine, it does exactly what I need, but the column under the {keypair.Name} displays [NONE] I am not sure if I am using the proper parameter name - I know there are few keypairNames.epm attached on my EC2 instances when I login to the console, but I am not seeing that on my report that I run by the command below. Any input is much appreciated.. Thx !

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],InstanceId,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress,InstanceType,PublicDnsName,keypair.Name]' --output table --region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field called `keypair` in the `Instances` dictionary.

The closest is `KeyName`:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "InstanceId": "i-xxx", 
                    "KeyName": "foo", 
...
```

Therefore, you would use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],InstanceId,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress,InstanceType,PublicDnsName,KeyName]'
```

See: [describe-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

Comment: Thanks John, I already tried keyname, but I am still getting NONE in my report. Also, in the sample you posted, I would need to give it a key name and instance id - this is not what I need. Lets say you do not have access to AWS console, how am I suppose to know the instance id and its keypair ?  For this reason I am running a report via AWS CLI to get all the metada I need.

How about if we do this - give me all instance IDs for a region and their related keypair names. It doesn't matter if you use Boto3, Jason, AWS CLI etc..   Thx.

Comment: Please see the last column - it shows NONE

|  windows|  running  |  m4.2xlarge  |  None |

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to incorporate `KeyName` in the request.

Comment: Very interesting ! I had no idea this thing is case sensitive.. I used the word ( keyname } all lowercase, in return I got the word: NONE. But it did work when I changed it to the way you have it:  { KeyName }.  Thanks so much John !

Comment: If you could throw one bonus as to how I can sort this out by PLATFORM that would be awesome :) 
Lastly, where do I check that your answer fixed my issue so you can get a credit ? Thanks again !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sort this out by PLATFORM". The `Platform` field will either contain `Windows` or `None`. If you are wanting to sort the results, you'll need to do that outside of the `aws` command. If you want some more control over results, I'd recommend using Python to call the API rather than using the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to sort this out by using pipe. exp:  | sort -k5

Please note, before I used {sort}, the report had {windows} and {None} allover the place under column PLATFORM. Please see attached, I uploaded a sample result of my report..

The new statement looks like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],InstanceId,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress,InstanceType,KeyName]' --output table | sort -k5
```

[Report shows that is sorted by PLATFORM IN Asc order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RsJk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I do the following for a few reasons

- it can be easily piped to grep
- you don't need to query aws api's repeatedly if you want to improve your data
- I have multiple regions that I'm usually iterating through, so this makes it easy to scan through all regions (and accounts)

```
instances=`aws ec2 describe-instances `
echo $instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | "[\(.InstanceId) \(.Platform) \(.State.Name) \(.PrivateIpAddress) \(.PublicIpAddress) \(.InstanceType) \(.PublicDnsName) \(.KeyName)]"'
```