# Only include array values if they exist in jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, jq

**End Goal**

*I want to display specific data for all returned AMIs and include tags `when they exist`, otherwise, a blank `tags` key is fine.*

---

**What I've Tried So Far**

Working command not including tag information here:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description}'
```

What I can't figure out is how to (optionally) include the data contained in the Tags[] array.  The command below works `for anything that has tags`, but I get a `jq: error (at <stdin>:451): Cannot iterate over null (null)` error whenever it hits a result that doesn't contain any tags.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags? | from_entries)}'
```

---

I feel like I'm close but could use some help figuring out the syntax for the optional `tags` key.  Any suggestions?

Sample Output from the last command:

```
{
  "amiName": "os42testclusterXXXXXXXXX",
  "imageId": "ami-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "creationDate": "2020-02-18T21:52:27.000Z",
  "description": "OpenShift 4 42XXXXXXXXXX",
  "tag": {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/os42testclusterXXXXXXXX": "owned",
    "Name": "os42testclusterXXXXXXXXX",
    "sourceAMI": "ami-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "sourceRegion": "us-west-2"
  }
}
{
  "amiName": "StudentMicroK8s",
  "imageId": "ami-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "creationDate": "2020-02-10T18:21:12.000Z",
  "description": "Base Image for K8s",
  "tag": {
    "Name": "StudentMicroK8sImage"
  }
}
{
  "amiName": "BOSH-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "imageId": "ami-XXXXXXXXXX",
  "creationDate": "2018-08-31T04:07:36.000Z",
  "description": "bosh-aws-xen-hvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent 3586.40",
  "tag": {
    "Name": "bosh-aws-xen-hvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent 3586.40"
  }
}
jq: error (at <stdin>:451): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Comment: **Tip:** You can use the `--query` parameter instead of using `jq`. For example: [amazon web services - AWS CLI - aws ec2 describe-instances to retrieve keypair mame for each EC2 instance - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299615/aws-cli-aws-ec2-describe-instances-to-retrieve-keypair-mame-for-each-ec2-insta) However, it will probably have the same problem with empty tags.

Comment: The sample is not a valid JSON value. Fix it if you're looking for a JQ solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that you can try is to list all AMI, and then select only those AMI which tags is not null.
For example

```
jq 'select(.tag != null)'
```

the final command will be

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags?)}' | jq 'select(.tag != null)'
```

Sample output

```
{
  "amiName": "test",
  "imageId": "ami-abcd8c96",
  "creationDate": "2020-04-11T09:50:26.000Z",
  "description": "test",
  "tag": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**update:**

base on the comment, you can combine the output of `null` and `not null`.

```
{ aws ec2 describe-images --owners self | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags?)}' | jq 'select(.tag == null)' && aws ec2 describe-images --owners self | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags?)}' | jq 'select(.tag != null)'; }
```

output

```
{
  "amiName": "test",
  "imageId": "ami-test",
  "creationDate": "2018-04-11T09:50:26.000Z",
  "description": "test",
  "tag": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "test"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "amiName": "test",
  "imageId": "ami-test",
  "creationDate": "2018-04-11T09:50:26.000Z",
  "description": "test",
  "tag": null

}
```

or if you want query once then you can try

```
{ AMI=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners self); echo $AMI | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags?)}' | jq 'select(.tag == null)' && echo $AMI | jq '.Images[] | {amiName: .Name, imageId: .ImageId, creationDate: .CreationDate, description: .Description, tag: (.Tags?)}' | jq 'select(.tag != null)'; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I've figured out how to get around the null values but I'm **expecting** that there will be some AMIs with no tags.  I don't want to exclude those.  I just want to exclude the `tags` key if it does come back as null.

Comment: check the updated answer. hope this is what you want